# Translating regular wording into a mathematical expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Given a product that initially costs $2000$ dollars and will cost $200$ dollars more on each subsequent purchase (for example a total of $6600$ spent on the third purchase), how would I write a function to calculate the TOTAL cost of purchasing the product $x$ amount of times?

Comment: What have you tried? Alternatively, what is the context behind this problem; where did you find it, and what relevant knowledge do you have?

Comment: Formula for a sum of arithmetic progression

Answer (score 0):

We can find the total cost *y* for *x* amount of purchases of this product using the formula for the sum of an arithmetic progression:

$$y=\frac{x}{2}(2a+(x-1)d)$$

where *a* equals the initial price of 2000 dollars
where *d* equals the common difference of 200 dollars

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.